# call several time the same subprocess python function

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, multiprocessing

I need to process-parallelize some computations that are done several time.
So the subprocess python function has to keep alive between two calls.

In a perfect world I would need something like that:

```
class Computer:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        # Creation of quite heavy python objects that cannot be pickled !!

    def call(self, y):
        return x+y


process =  Computer(4) ## NEED MAGIC HERE to keep "call" alive in a subprocess !!

print(process.call(1))   # prints 5   (=4+1)
print(process.call(12))  # prints 16 (=4+12)
```

I can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56051270/5371582) and communicate via `asyncio.subprocess.PIPE`, but in my actual use case,

- the `call` argument is a list of list of integers
- the `call` answer is a list of strings

Thus it could be cool to avoid to serialize/deserialize the arguments and return values by hand.

Any ideas of how to keep the function `call` "alive" and ready to receive new calls ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer, based on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56051270/5371582), but

- several subprocesses are created
- each subprocess has its own identifier
- their calls are parallelized
- a small layer to allow exchange of jsons instead of plain byte strings.

**hello.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


# This is the taks to be done.
# A task consist in receiving a json assumed to be
# {"vector": [...]}
# and return a json with the length of the vector and
# the worker id.

import sys
import time
import json


ident = sys.argv[1]


while True:
    str_data = input()
    data = json.loads(str_data)

    command = data.get("command", None)

    if command == "quit":
        answer = {"comment": "I'm leaving",
                  "my id": ident}
        print(json.dumps(answer), end="\n")
        sys.exit(1)

    time.sleep(1)   # simulates 1s of heavy work
    answer = {"size": len(data['vector']),
              "my id": ident}
    print(json.dumps(answer), end="\n")
```

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


dprint = print


def create_proc(arg):
    cmd = ["./hello.py", arg]
    process = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    return process


def make_call(proc, arg):
    """Make the call in a thread."""
    str_arg = json.dumps(arg)
    txt = bytes(str_arg + '\n', encoding='utf8')
    proc.stdin.write(txt)
    proc.stdin.flush()
    b_ans = proc.stdout.readline()

    s_ans = b_ans.decode('utf8')
    j_ans = json.loads(s_ans)

    return j_ans


def search(executor, procs, data):
    jobs = [executor.submit(make_call, proc, data) for proc in procs]

    answer = []
    for job in concurrent.futures.as_completed(jobs):
        got_ans = job.result()
        answer.append(got_ans)
    return answer


def main():
    n_workers = 50
    idents = [f"{i}st" for i in range(0, n_workers)]
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(n_workers)

    # Create `n_workers` subprocesses waiting for data to work with.
    # The subprocesses are all different because they receive different
    # "initialization" id.
    procs = [create_proc(ident) for ident in idents]

    data = {"vector": [1, 2, 23]}
    answers = search(executor, procs, data)  # takes 1s instead of 5 !
    for answer in answers:
        print(answers)

    search(executor, procs, {"command": "quit"})


main()
```